# Spring security : migrating 4.0 to 5.0 - Error -There is no PasswordEncoder mapped for the id “null”

Tags: spring, spring-security

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: There is no PasswordEncoder mapped for the id "null"
    org.springframework.security.crypto.password.DelegatingPasswordEncoder$UnmappedIdPasswordEncoder.matches(DelegatingPasswordEncoder.java:236)
    org.springframework.security.crypto.password.DelegatingPasswordEncoder.matches(DelegatingPasswordEncoder.java:196)
    org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter$LazyPasswordEncoder.matches(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:593)
```

My code was working fine, now i have changed the spring security version from 4.0 to 5.0, and its not working

Answer (score 10):

for Java based, make these changes in your code and update it as

```
@Autowired
public void configureGlobalSecurity(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    BCryptPasswordEncoder encoder = passwordEncoder();
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("admin").password(encoder.encode("admin")).roles("ADMIN");
}

@Bean
public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}
```

or,

```
 @Bean
public static NoOpPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
 return (NoOpPasswordEncoder) NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
}
```

for XML configuration,

```
<bean id ="passwordEncoder" class = "org.springframework.security.crypto.NoOpPasswordEncoder" factory-method = "getInstance" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Please read through the link here for the updates you need to do for this:-

https://spring.io/blog/2017/11/01/spring-security-5-0-0-rc1-released#password-storage-format.

You may need to add bean for the password encoder in your class, that will again depend on your requirements

For example you can use the `NoOpPasswordEncoder` in your configuration class like below:-

```
@Bean
public NoOpPasswordEncoder noopPasswordEncoder(){
    return new NoOpPasswordEncoder();
}
```

And for XML based Configuration like below:-

```
<bean id ="passwordEncoder" class = "org.springframework.security.crypto.NoOpPasswordEncoder" factory-method = "getInstance" />
```