# There is no PasswordEncoder mapped for the id "null" in DelegatingPasswordEncoder

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data

I am New on Spring Security.using Spring 4.3 and Spring Security 5.0 .Everything
Run .the login page also came .if you given Wrong Password it tells Your login attempt was not successful, try again.Fine But Right Password give it raised Exception

my Spring_Security . XML is

```
 <authentication-manager>  
      <authentication-provider>  
        <user-service>  
        <user name="admin" password="1234" authorities="ROLE_USER" />  
        </user-service>  
      </authentication-provider>  
    </authentication-manager>
```

my Web.xml

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml,
         /WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/hibernate.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>



<listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>




<filter>  
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>  
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>  
</filter>  
<filter-mapping>  
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>  
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>  
</filter-mapping>  





<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
     <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

my Controller Class

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/admin", method=RequestMethod.GET)  
        public String privateHome() {  

            return "privatePage";  
        }  


When Run the Code /admin page its default run log in page .Everything Fine
```

.Once Right Credentials Given i got There is no Password Encoder mapped  for 
    the id "null"

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49654143/spring-security-5-there-is-no-passwordencoder-mapped-for-the-id-null

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49609768/spring-security-migrating-4-0-to-5-0-error-there-is-no-passwordencoder-mapp

Comment: these Links are Tell about the Spring Boot .But I want in Spring xml based

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49122867/spring-boot-2-0-0-oauth2

Answer (score 0):

You can lookup the answers for this question: [Spring security : migrating 4.0 to 5.0 - Error -There is no PasswordEncoder mapped for the id “null”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49609768/spring-security-migrating-4-0-to-5-0-error-there-is-no-passwordencoder-mapp/49609885#49609885)

However, for Spring Security 5, the correct definition would be:

```
<bean id ="passwordEncoder" class = "org.springframework.security.crypto.password.NoOpPasswordEncoder" factory-method = "getInstance" />
```